# Enable XPath/XSLT document function for Visual Studio 2022 debugger

Tags: c#, xpath, xslt-1.0, visual-studio-2022

I'm writing a C# program incorporating XSLT.  Visual Studio throws the following warning for my XSLT:

`Execution of the 'document()' function was prohibited. Use the XsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction property to enable it.`

Trouble is, I have not yet written the C# handling of the XML, and therefore can't set the property.  The only reader is the debugger, and I can't find any relevant code in the pregenerated property files, nor any option in Visual Studio's UI to set it for this.  Does anyone know where the `XsltSettings` is?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same answer, but I just tried it, i.e. I ran the xslt in debug and non debug and it worked, the issue appears to be a warning in the editor, but it doesnt impact me running it.